# C# Sample for Generating AZURE V3 Token for premium CDN token authentication

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

On ASP.NET C# site need to generate Azure V3 tokens on the fly for premium CDN token authentication.
Is the any API or some tool for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [Nugget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ECToken#dependencies-body-tab) for that.

Sample use:

```
const string PRIMARY_KEY = "abcd1234";

var generator = new ecencryptstdlib.ECTokenGenerator();

string token = generator.EncryptV3(PRIMARY_KEY, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
```